# Return Value from PHP Function is Empty

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I'm trying to return the results of an API call but for the life of me, cannot get them outside of this function. I don't work with PHP that often but this seems like it should work. I also tried using globals (bad, I know) but those don't work either.

getProdVariantsAsync is a function inside the ProductVariation Class. It passes the results to the Results Class and returns the JSON formatted data.

All that works. What I can't figure out is how to get $results->json() outside of the getProdVariants function.

**UPDATE:** Using Guzzle framework

```
$prodVariants = new ProductVariation($api);

function getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku) {
    $promise = $prodVariants->getProdVariantsAsync($sku, 0, 200);

    // The Result Class is called here
    $promise->then(function($results) {
        return $results->json();
    });
}

$products = getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku);

echo json_encode($products);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
class Result {
    public $correlationId;
    public $body;
    public $etag;
    public $contentType;

    public function json() {
        return json_decode($this->body);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I ended up figuring it out. I needed to use the wait function to force the promise to complete. Thank you everyone for the guidance and suggestions. This is what I did to get it working:

```
$prodVariants = new ProductVariation($api);

function getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku) {
    $promise = $prodVariants->getProdVariantsAsync($sku, 0, 200);

    return $promise->then(function($results) {
        return $results->json();
    });
}

$products = getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku)->wait(function($results){
    return $results;
});

echo json_encode($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$prodVariants = new ProductVariation($api);

function getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku) {
    $promise = $prodVariants->getProdVariantsAsync($sku, 0, 200);

    return $promise->then(function($results) {
        return $results->json();
    });
}

$products = getProdVariants($prodVariants, $sku)->wait(function($results){
    return $results;
});

echo json_encode($products);
```

For more information and implementations see:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

https://github.com/guzzle/promises

https://github.com/reactphp/promise

Comment: Thanks Tino, however this did not work either. It still returns empty.

Comment: Perhaps the promise / api call work not properly. Do you get something, when printing out the result inside the then() function for testing ?

Comment: Yes, when I echo $results->json(); there are results. It's the weirdest thing.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'am new to those react style promise functions. I just know those _callback hells_ from JS. Because is async you can't use it like this. I will correct my awnser.

Comment: Hi Tino, sorry for the delay, I had to jump on another project. I tried this (thanks btw) and $results is undefined when passing it to the callback. I'm reading up on promises, specifically Guzzle. There's a wait method that forces the promise to complete, however, it only returns the $correlationId, $etag and $contentType. $body is empty.

Comment: @kakihara: Nice that you could solve it! Sorry for my wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the anonymous function into the `then()` method.  Assuming `then()` returns something to `getProdVariants()` function, you need to return from `getProdVariants()`:

```
return $promise->then(function($results) {
                          return $results->json();
                      });
```

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver but that still returns empty:( The results are there when I echo $results->json();

Comment: That means the `then()` method isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `function` should return `$promise` , currently it returns nothing.

Then you have to get the `Callable Function` setted with `then` before.
like `$result = $products->getThen();`

After that you can do `echo json_encode($result($args));`